# Choose a default/fallback color shade from colors object in Chakra UI theme

Tags: reactjs, themes, chakra-ui

I'm willing to use a voilet color with different shades in my Chakra theme. But one of the shades is going to be used more often and I would like to use it as default.

```js
export const theme = extendTheme({
  colors: {
     voilet: {
       _default: '#7f56d9', // THIS IS THE voilet.500
      50: "#f2eefb",
      100: "#e0d6f6",
      200: "#c8b6ef",
      300: "#ae95e7",
      400: "#9674e0",
      500: "#7f56d9",
      600: "#6c49b8",
      700: "#5a3d9a",
      800: "#48317c",
      900: "#392762",
    },
  },
});
```

Instead of using voilet.500 over and over, I would like to just use voilet.

The _default keyword does not seem to work.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: similar issue is present on github as well without sol. https://github.com/chakra-ui/chakra-ui/discussions/5871